# Setting new environments with LaTeX

Tags: environments, tabu

I was attempting to simplify my LaTeX document to write a Maths assessment with LaTeX, but when I created new environments I got an error that I cannot solve. Can you please explain me what is wrong with my definition? The source is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}

% ASSESSMENT TEXT
\newenvironment{assessment}
    {\tabulinesep=1.5mm
     \begin{longtabu} to \linewidth{|X[13 l]|X[c]|}
     \hline
      & \scriptsize DO NOT WRITE IN THIS MARGIN \cr}
    {\end{longtabu}}

% Pattern \begin{AssExer}{mark}{space}
\newcounter{exercise}
\newenvironment{AssExerc}[2]
    {\hline
     \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
     \refstepcounter{exercise}\textbf{\theexercise.}~}
    {\end{minipage}\vspace{#2} & \textbf{#1}\cr
     \hline}

\begin{document}
\begin{assessment}
\begin{AssExerc}{1}{2cm}
Solve the following equation $2x-1 = 0$.
\end{AssExerc}
\end{assessment}
\end{document}
```

The assessment environment works, but the AssExerc doesn't. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Well, first of all, you need to provide an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) (Minimum Working Example), so that we can try to compile your code and see the errors for ourselves. Also, maybe you just have a typo, if you copied this from your code: the `\newenvironment{AssExer}` is missing the c.

Comment: I copied only the definitions because the code is kind of a nightmare! I am copying now the source with a minimal working example. Perhaps it is not that minimal and I apologise for that, but I honestly do not know how to provide a minimal one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few problems with your code. First, you cannot use an argument to an environment in the `\end{environment}` code. We can get around this by putting the arguments into temporary global variables `\gdef\temppoints{#1}\gdef\tempvskip{#2}`.

The second more bothersome issue is that the environment starts a group and inside that group you cannot add elements to the table like `&` or `\cr` or `\hline`. To get around this, we can use `\AfterEndEnvironment` which adds code after the environment group is ended and is defined in the `etoolbox` package. We need to move `& \textbf{#1}\cr\hline` into `\AfterEndEnvironment`. I don't have a similar workaround for the `\hline` in the `\begin{AssExer}` part, but luckily that `\hline` is unneeded.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% ASSESSMENT TEXT
\newenvironment{assessment}
    {\tabulinesep=1.5mm
     \begin{longtabu} to \linewidth{|X[13 l]|X[c]|}
     \hline
      & \scriptsize DO NOT WRITE IN THIS MARGIN \cr\hline}
    {\end{longtabu}}

% Pattern \begin{AssExer}{mark}{space}
\newcounter{exercise}
\newenvironment{AssExer}[2]{
     \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
     \refstepcounter{exercise}\textbf{\theexercise.}~
     \gdef\temppoints{#1}\gdef\tempvspace{#2}
}{
     \end{minipage}\vspace{\tempvspace} 
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{AssExer}{& \textbf{\temppoints}\cr\hline}

\begin{document}

\begin{assessment}
\begin{AssExer}{1}{2cm}
Solve the following equation $2x-1 = 0$.
\end{AssExer}
\end{assessment}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfectly now. I did not know of these packages! I realise my attempt was kind of naif!

Comment: Actually the `\AfterEndEnviornment` problem is nasty -- it's hard to fix that sort of problem.